# How do I detect the pattern of the knock on a door, and use it as a signature to unlock a door?

Tags: sound, microcontroller, arduino, sensor

How do I detect the pattern of the knock on a door, and use it as a signature to unlock a door?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This site has fairly detailed answers to how they did it

http://grathio.com/2009/11/secret-knock-detecting-door-lock.html

Method description from that webpage, for permanence:

> A microphone (okay, really a speaker) presses against the door and
>   listens for knocks.  If it hears the right number of knocks in the
>   right cadence it triggers the motor to turn the deadbolt and unlock
>   the door.  If the sequence isn't recognized, the system resets and
>   listens for knocks again.

Comment: what sample rate is needed to accurately distinguish the knock from other types of stuff?

Answer (score 4):

From [Make magazine's blog](http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2009/11/secret_knock_detector.html):

> [image]
>
> RFID card readers becoming passé?
>   Maybe what you need to guard the door
>   to your high-tech lair is a [secret
>   knock detecting door lock](http://grathio.com/2009/11/secret-knock-detecting-door-lock.html). Using
>   an Arduino and a bunch of parts found
>   around the lab, Steve Hoefer built a
>   device that unlocks your door when it
>   receives a certain knock pattern. It
>   works by counting the time between
>   successive knocks, and can be
>   re-programmed at the touch of a
>   button.
>
> Of course, this system is susceptible
>   to a [replay attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack), because
>   anyone can listen to the knock pattern
>   and then know how to get in. If you
>   are planning to use something like
>   this, I would recommend either
>   incorporating a [timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) into
>   the message, or using a series of [one
>   time knocks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_password), in order to make it
>   harder to break into. Actually, that
>   might make it more secure than a
>   regular lock.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easy way would be to measure time between knocks using a microcontroller.
To detect the knocks you can use an electret microphone connected to a Diferential Amplifier, and its output shuld be the trigger of a 555 timer configured as monostable.
The monostable output then is connected to a "Capture And Compare Pin" of the microcontroller.
All the rest is just coding.